# Не получается вывести ассоциативный массив

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть код и не могу вывести ассоциативный массив, выдает ошибку

```
 $rows = $pdo->query("SELECT post_id, date, author, content, name_image FROM post_en LEFT JOIN image_post ON post_id=id_post_en")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$posts = $imgs = [];
foreach($rows as $row->fetch_assoc()){
    $imgs[$row['post_id']][] = $row['name_image'];
    $row['images'] = $imgs[$row['post_id']];
    $posts[$row['post_id']] = $row;
}
```

вот что нужно выводить[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А код самой ошибки приложить?

Comment: @SkyFox там все одна большая ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде целый набор удивительных ошибок. Например:

1. `$rows` это первая строка результата (массив), а не весь результат
2. `$row` в `foreach` это элемент предыдущего массива, а не следующая строка датасета
3. `fetch_assoc()` это вообще неизвестный метод, вызванный у примитивных типов

и т.п.

Вы вот извлекли набор новостей или постов с присоединенными картинками, теперь вам надо извлечь их все и сгруппировать. PDO предоставляет такой функционал, используйте `fetchAll` с флагом `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`

```
$data = $pdo->query("select post_id ....")
            ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

вы получите массив  с уникальными ключами из `post_id`. Значениями будет массив соответствующих строк. Поскольку `date, author,content` у вас повторяются, то их можно взять из первой строки, а вот `image` оставить массивом.
Для этих целей воспользуйтесь, например, `array_map()`

```
$result = array_map(function($rows){
                 $post = $rows[0];
                 $post['name_image'] = array_column($rows, 'name_image');
                 return $post;
             }, $data);
```

в итоге должны получить (не проверял) результат вида

```
[
   1 => [
     'date' => .... 
     'author' =>  ....
     'content' => ...
     'name_image' => [
         'image1.jpg', 
         'image2.jpg,
         ....
      ]
   ],
   2 => [
      'date' => ...
      ....
   ]
]
```

*Такие штуки куда удобнее извлекать двумя запросами.  Сначала получаете посты, оттуда нужные id, а потом и картинки для них, сразу делая группировку. Затем просто сливаете результаты вместе. 
Тут с одной стороны вы делаете один запрос вместо двух к БД, но зато при таком запросе извлекается и передается клиенту куда больший объем данных чем нужно.*

Comment: все супер, спасибо